# “Add to homescreen” Android icon mane not showing

Tags: android, google-chrome, homescreen, home-screen-widget

I added meta info so that it should be pinned to iOS and Android homescreens and should be launched as a web app.
I use this one tutorial to add the add to home screen callout [ATH](https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen), bit on Android icon name is not showing - it takes Page title instead of short name in meta tag. If somebody met this one issue give the pls advise where can I fix it. thanks

my head

```
meta(name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable', content='yes')
meta(name='mobile-web-app-capable', content='yes')
meta(name='apple-mobile-web-app-title', content='Add to Home')
link(rel='shortcut icon', sizes='16x16', href='../images/ath-app-icon.jpg')
link(rel='shortcut icon', sizes='196x196', href='../images/ath-app-icon.jpg')
link(rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed', href='../images/ath-app-icon.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to write Your Short name in Your Manifest.Json File short_name="your Short Name" then it will appear when you are adding to home screen

```js
{
  "name": "Any Name",
  "short_name": "Your Short name",
  "icons": [
  {
        "src": "120x120.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "128x128"
      }, 
   ],
  "start_url": "anyUrl?launcher=true",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "background_color": "#aac73c ",
  "theme_color": "#63528a"
}
```